# Getting attr value set using option.attr('label', value['labelvalue']);

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down which displays 'value2'. Its id is "select" like below.

```
<select class="selectOneMenu_Medium_class searchField" id="selectBase">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
</select>
```

```js
option.attr('value', value['value']);
option.text(value['value2']);
option.attr('label', value['value2']);
```

Whenever I try to retrieve the value using `$('#selectBase').val()` it gives me a value, but I want `value2` also along with this. Can someone helps me in fetching `value2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selected` psuedo selector and jquery `text` method

```js
$('#selectBase').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  console.log($("#selectBase option:selected").text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectOneMenu_Medium_class searchField" id="selectBase">
  <option value="Select">Value 2</option>
  <option value="Select1">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I thought the user wanted to obtain value of a custom attribute of the selected option - on a hind sight perhaps even text would work for him :)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Implementation

```js
$('#selectBase').on('change', function() {

  let myValue = $(this).val(),
    myLabel = $("#selectBase option:selected").attr("label"),
    myText = $("#selectBase option:selected").text();

  console.log(
    "Value is", myValue, "\n",
    "ValueOfAttribute is", myLabel, "\n",
    "Text is", myText);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectBase">
  
  <option value="Select1" label="myLabel1">Value 1
  </option>
  
  <option value="Select2" label="myLabel2">Value 2
  </option>
  
</select>
```

Java-Script Implementation

```js
function selectChanged(ref) {

  let index = ref.selectedIndex;
  let myValue = ref.value;
  let myLabel = ref.options[index].getAttribute("label");
  let myText = ref.options[index].text;

  console.log(
    "Value is", myValue, "\n",
    "ValueOfAttribute is", myLabel, "\n",
    "Text is", myText, "\n", );
}
```

```html
<select id="myselect" onChange="selectChanged(this)">
  <option value="Select1" label="valOfLabel1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="Select2" label="valOfLabel2">Val 2</option>
</select>
```